# KivyMD, Unable to update the value in the label frequently for every iteration

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create the coin toss app, I have set a timer where It should start from 3,2,1 and that has to be updated on the label. but this initial shows 3 and after 2 seconds it shows 1 it doesn't show 2.
kindly please help to fix the issue

this is my .py file.

This is my code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
import random
import time
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors
seconds=3
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    title = "COIN TOSS"
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '300'
        screen = Screen()
        return Builder.load_file('toss.kv')
    def show_MDDialog(self, wrongvalue=None):
        my_dialog = MDDialog(title="Wrong Input", text="Kindly please Enter the right value either HEADS OR TAILS. You have enter "+wrongvalue, size_hint = [.5,.5])
        my_dialog.open()

    def clear(self):
        self.root.ids.result.text = ""
        self.root.ids.actualtoss.text = ""
        self.root.ids.cointoss.text = ""

    def choice(self):
        heads = self.root.ids.heads.text
        print(heads)

    def countdown(self):
        global seconds
        if int(self.root.ids.counter.text) == 3:
            for i in range(seconds):
                timer = str(seconds - i)
                self.root.ids.counter.text = timer
                print(timer)
                time.sleep(1)
                self.play()
        else:
            self.root.ids.counter.text = str(seconds)


    def play(self):
        # playing = True
        # while playing == True:
        coin = ["heads", "tails"]
        toss = random.choice(coin)

        selection = self.root.ids.heads.text
        if selection != " ":
            if selection.lower() == "heads" or selection.lower() == "tails":
                if selection.lower() == toss:
                    print("The actual toss is", toss)
                    print("You Won")
                    self.root.ids.result.text = "You WON "

                else:
                    self.root.ids.result.text = "You LOOSE "

            else:
                self.show_MDDialog(selection)
        else:
            self.show_MDDialog(selection)


DemoApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<Root>
    MDToolbar:
        title: app.title

        elevation: 10

MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: [227/255,225/255,253/255,1]
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            title: "COIN TOSS"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x : print("menu is clicked")]]
            right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x : print("dots is clicked")]]

        MDLabel:
            text:"COIN TOSS"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 40
            padding_x : 20
            bold: True
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.9}

        MDLabel:
            italic: True
            underline: True
            text: "Choice"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: [9/255,28/255,27/255,1]
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.8}
            font_style: "H5"
            halign: "center"


        MDFloatingActionButton:
            id: heads
            text: "heads"
            icon: "heads.png"
            #md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            size_hint: .2, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2 , 'center_y':0.7}
            on_press: app.choice()


        MDLabel:
            id: counter
            text:"3"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 40
            padding_x : 20
            bold: True
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7}



        MDFloatingActionButton:
            id: tails
            text: "tails"
            icon: "tails.png"
            #md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            size_hint: .198, .198
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.8 , 'center_y':0.7}
            on_press: app.choice1()

        MDLabel:
            id: result
            text:""
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 60
            padding_x : 20
            bold: True
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}


        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Click for TOSS"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
            on_press:
                app.countdown()


        MDBottomAppBar:

            MDToolbar:
                title: "v1   R Bharath"
                icon: "account"
                icon_color: [1,.3,.5,.4]
                md_bg_color: [1,.9,.5,.7]
                specific_text_color: [9/255,28/255,27/255,1]
                type: "bottom" #end, free-end, free-center
                round: 50
                on_action_button: app.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running a method (`countdown()`) with a loop on the main thread. As long as that method is holding the main thread, no updates will occur to your display (those updates are done on the main thread and cannot run until the main thread is available). When the `countdown()` method finally returns, all the waiting display updates are performed (too quickly to see intermediate updates).

You can fix the problem by running that loop in another `Thread`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#thread-objects). If you do that, you must also manage to get the updates to your display (like setting the `text` of a `Label`) back on the main thread. To do that you can define a method that just does that update, then call it using `Clock.schedule_once()` or perhaps just give it a `@mainthread` decorator.

Another approach is to use `Clock.schedule_interval()` to schedule calls to a method that does the stuff in that loop without actually using a loop. That way all your display updates are done on the main thread and the main thread is not tied up for the entire loop. This would require some redesign of your code, including keeping track of the clock event so that you can cancel it after the 3 seconds.